# How to convert this Oracle stored procedure into a SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, loops, stored-procedures, sql-server-2017

I have a stored procedure from Oracle mentioned below which gets a comma seperated string parameter as input, splits it via a loop and returns the path of the id got from splitting the csv. How do I create a procedure which works same like this in SQL Server?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE FILE_LOOP(V_FID IN varchar2,
                                      V_NAME OUT VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
  FOR ITEM IN (SELECT  V.PATHH||'\'|| V.NAME AS PATH 
               FROM  FILES T INNER JOIN 
                     Table2 V ON T.FOLID=V.ID 
               WHERE T.ID IN (SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(V_FID,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL))
                              FROM DUAL
                              CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1+ REGEXP_COUNT(V_FID , ',')))
  LOOP
     v_name:=v_name||item.PATH;
  END LOOP;

END;
```

Please help me write a procedure which gives exact same output in sql server? I'm new to sql server.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want :

```
if object_id('FILE_LOOP', 'P') is not null
  drop procedure FILE_LOOP;
go

create PROCEDURE 
  FILE_LOOP(
  @V_FID varchar(4000),
  @V_NAME VARCHAR(4000) OUT) AS
  BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
   DECLARE ITEM CURSOR FOR
   SELECT 
   ISNULL(V.PATHH, '') + '' +
   ISNULL(V.NAME, '') AS PATH 
   FROM 
   FILES T 
   INNER JOIN Table2 V ON T.FOLID=V.ID 
   WHERE T.ID IN( SELECT 
      RTRIM(LTRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(@V_FID ,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL));
      FROM DUAL 
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 + REGEXP_COUNT(@V_FID ,',')))
  WHILE 1=1 
  BEGIN
  set @v_name=isnull(@V_NAME, '') + ISNULL(item.PATH, '');
  END;

 FETCH ITEM INTO;
 END;
 CLOSE ITEM;
 DEALLOCATE ITEM;
```

Comment: REGEXP_SUBSTR is not available in SQL server. Is there any replacement for that to split the string and consider only one value at a time?

Comment: Likewise DUAL is peculiar to Oracle. Whilst the Seeker could easily create a DUAL table of their own in SQL Server it would not be idiomatic T-SQL.

Comment: Likewise no CONNECT BY LEVEL in SQL Server. And REGEXP_COUNT ???  Loop 'WHILE 1=1 ...' looks strange to me ...

Answer (score 0):

One way converting this procedure from Oracle to Sql Server is using cursors:

```
CREATE or alter PROCEDURE FILE_LOOP
    @V_FID NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @V_NAME NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Item NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT TRIM(value) AS ID
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@V_FID, ',');

    SET @V_NAME = '';

    OPEN cur;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Item;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @V_NAME = @V_NAME + ' ' + V.PATHH + '\' + V.NAME
        FROM FILES T
        INNER JOIN Table2 V ON T.FOLID = V.ID
        WHERE T.ID = @Item;

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Item;
    END;

    CLOSE cur;
    DEALLOCATE cur;
END;
```

You can execute the procedure in this way:

```
DECLARE @OutputName NVARCHAR(MAX);
EXEC FILE_LOOP @V_FID ='11,22,33,444,98', @V_NAME = @OutputName OUTPUT;
SELECT @OutputName AS Result;
```